# Can Aframe do a Split-Screen effect showing two scenes?

Tags: aframe

I am aware that aframe commonly uses one single scene only (except when using iframe) - However, I was wondering if it would be possible to have it show two different scenes and a slider that could show one scene on the left of the slider and the other scene in the right.

This is an example using ThreeJS:
https://codepen.io/looeee/pen/jpebjN

This code uses multiple scenes like this:

```
  function render() {

    renderer.setScissor( 0, 0, sliderPos, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.render( sceneL, camera );

    renderer.setScissor( sliderPos, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.render( sceneR, camera );

  }
```

I have been trying to figure out solutions that could use aframe to make this happen, but I hit roadblocks every time... Before I go a full threejs route I thought I'd ask here and see if anyone has other ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in THREEjs and Aframe is built on top, so the answer is that it can be done.
Here is the example for how it is done in THREEjs.
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html

Comment: I probably should be a bit more specific with my post (will edit it), I know it is possible to do multiple views in ThreeJS as I put a link to an existing example I'd like to replicate using Aframe.

The example you provided (same as mine) use multiple scenes, where as Aframe relies on only one. Adding multiple ones via iframe or embedded stops them from interacting with each other the same way the examples are.

This makes me a little unsure about the Aframe implementation

Comment: It is not an easy thing to do in Aframe. If I were to try to make this in aframe, I'd probably make a component attached to one camera that effectively renders that three js scene. Then attach the same component to the other camera. Finally put the renders as textures on planes parented to a third camera and render that a the final output.

Comment: Oh! That's a solution I didn't think of... I'll play with the idea for a bit then.
Otherwise, I'll just fall back to a pure ThreeJS solution - Just interested in using AFrame to stay in line with the rest of the framework... But not worth it if it's going to make things overly complicated.

Comment: Here is a glitch that shows how to access THREEjs objects and make  materials in a component. https://glitch.com/~shadow-material